# python beatifulsoup returns only key {} not a value

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I spend today several hours to scrape some data from this website:http://www.buienradar.nl/weer/kingston/jm/3489854/5daagse
I try to get the data inside the orange box.[weather data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug9P3.png)

I am on python 3 and use bs4

Whatever I try I only get a key-like result like {temperature}
How do i get the value's?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "http://www.buienradar.nl/weer/kingston/jm/3489854/5daagse"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
letters = soup.find_all("div", class_="forecast")

tempe = soup.find(class_='temperature').attrs
print(tempe)
table = soup.find(class_='precipitation').attrs
print(table)
heds = soup.find_all('table')
for h in heds:
    m = h.find_all('td')
    print(m)
    for o in m:
        print(o.text)
```

the outcome is:

```
   {'class': ['temperature']}
{'class': ['precipitation']}
[<td>{time}</td>, <td><img data-url="/resources/images/icons/weather/30x30/{iconcode}.png" src=""/></td>, <td><span class="temperature">{temperature}°C</span></td>, <td>{feeltemperature}°C</td>, <td>{winddirection} {beaufort}</td>, <td style="text-align:left;"><img data-url="/resources/images/icons/wind/{winddirection}.png" src="" style="width:20px;"/></td>, <td class="precipitation">{precipation}%</td>, <td>{precipationmm} mm</td>, <td>{sunshine}%</td>]
{time}

{temperature}°C
{feeltemperature}°C
{winddirection} {beaufort}

{precipation}%
{precipationmm} mm
{sunshine}%

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What do I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

EDIT thanks to the answers I got it up and running:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'path/to/selenium')
url = "http://www.buienradar.nl/weer/kingston/jm/3489854/5daagse"
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "forecast")))
print("access")
sleep(1)
html_page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")
letters = soup.find_all("div", class_="forecast")

tempe = soup.find(class_='temperature').attrs
print(tempe)
table = soup.find(class_='precipitation').attrs
print(table)
heds = soup.find_all('table')
for h in heds:
    m = h.find_all('td')
    print(m)
    for o in m:
        print(o.text)
```

Comment: what is desired output

Comment: The mm as pointed out in the orange box see photo link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get desired data faster and without `Selenium`  if you make a direct request to site api:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.buienradar.nl/data/forecast/1.1/all/3489854'
# Get json response
data = requests.get(url).json()
# Parse json response
for day in data['days']:
    if 'hours' in day:
        print(day['date'])
        for hour in day['hours']:
            print('Hour - {}.00 and Precipitation - {} mm'.format(hour['hour'], hour['precipationmm']))

# 2017-05-05T00:00:00
# Hour - 21.00 and Precipitation - 0.0 mm
# Hour - 22.00 and Precipitation - 0.0 mm
# Hour - 23.00 and Precipitation - 0.0 mm
# 2017-05-06T00:00:00
# Hour - 0.00 and Precipitation - 0.0 mm
# Hour - 1.00 and Precipitation - 0.0 mm
# Hour - 2.00 and Precipitation - 0.0 mm
```

Comment: Awesome thinking, I wasn't looking for an API since he asked for scraping and beautifulSoup that's one way to get the data but it might have some limitations/throttle.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong, you just aren't doing everything a browser is doing. This website particularly only serves a "template" when you fetch the URL and they rely on Javascript to fill in template values. If you open the "Networking" tab in Chrome you will see a bunch of requests. Specifically, https://static.buienradar.nl/resources/js/v/1.0.22/buienradar.min.js will perform a bunch of replacements including {temperature} and {feeltemperature}.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something like temeprature you're going to be doing it like this:

```
temp = soup.findAll('span',{'class':'temperature'}) 
#It's not spelled correctly make sure you take that into account
```

[image]
The **issue** here doesn't seem to be the ***code***, the temperature is generated by javascript or something else. *It's **dynamic***, therefore, you'll have to use something like Selenium (Automated browser)

Comment: I've submitted an edit, it wasn't my point the website's data is dynamic you can't just grab it with an get request on the page